# php-ssh2 installing an incompatible version on ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04, php-7.3

I am running `sudo apt-get install php-ssh2` on ubuntu.

The machine is running php 7.3 (we need to update it asap). The command installs php-ssh2 but it puts it in a php 8.1 folder and the ssh2_connect script is still throwing the following error:

Call to undefined function app\Console\Commands\Jobs\ssh2_connect()

I am executing from Laravel if that helps. How do I install php-ssh2 in a way that php 7.3 can access it? I have installed this package in the past and have not had this issue.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install php7.3-ssh2` ?

Comment: What else did you try? How did you install all the other PHP packages you are currently using?